# MULE 3.7.1 Database connector not running MS SQL Server native function

Tags: sql-server, database, mule, connector

I try to insert a record into MS SQL Server, in a table to record logs, which has a field of type Datetime2 by trying to insert a record function including: GETDATE() throws me the sieguiente error:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime2.

Now try placing the function in a SELECT like this:
(SELECT GETDATE())

But with the same result, so I see the query text inserts the GETDATE (), so not running the function to get the date, any solution to this problem?

Comment: Share you db component xml configurartion. Have you tried with a dynamic query type ?

Comment: The issue with the execution of the native function is present because MULE ran out of RAM space, to solve only restart MULE, I run correctly after this, even not because MULE was consuming too much RAM, what caused this small mistake, thank you for your response.